# Delete Older Duplicate record from Datatable C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with say 3 columns like below and it contains duplicate records. I want find the duplicate FileName records with same Id field and delete the older one by comparing the date field column. How can I do it in Linq? 
**Current**

## FileName || CreatedDate || Id

Test.pdf  ||   06/22/2020 ||      1
Test1.pdf ||   06/22/2020 ||      2
Test.pdf  ||   06/21/2020 ||      1
Test.pdf  ||   06/21/2020 ||      3

Delete this record - Test.pdf with Id = 1 because it was updated on 06/21.

**Expected**

## FileName || CreatedDate || Id#

Test.pdf   ||06/22/2020 || 1
Test1.pdf  ||06/22/2020 || 2
Test.pdf   ||06/21/2020 || 3

I'm able to fetch the duplicate records using below snippet by grouping the record by fileName but I'm not sure how to group the records by Id also

```
var filteredList = DT.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("FileName"))
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(dr => dr.Field<DateTime>("CreationDate")).First())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change what you're doing with the snippet that selects duplicates to get the filtered list of items you're looking for.

First, group the DataRows by the column "FileName". Now that you have the groups, order each group by the column CreatedDate in descending order and take the first DataRow from each group.

```
  var filteredList = DT.AsEnumerable()
         .GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("FileName"))
         .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(dr => dr.Field<DateTime>("CreatedDate")).First())
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton!. it looks to be working. I'll further test it

Comment: i think will be efficient if you call ``OrderBy`` before ``GroupBy`` instead calling it inside ``Select`` statement.

Comment: Thanks Blake and Sajid. It works as expected however while testing I realised I need to group the record by FileName as well as Id because that's what makes a record unique. Any pointers on how to group record by FileName as well as Id ?

Comment: You can use `GroupBy` to group by any number of properties by grouping them into an anonymous object. Change the GroupBy line to something like this: `.GroupBy(dr => new { FileName =  dr.Field<string>("FileName"), Id = dr.Field<int>("Id") } )`